# Changing a class after implementing with Test Driven Development

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The first class I wrote for my application using the TDD approach was a configuration file handler. I wrote the unit tests for all the methods I thought I would need and implemented the actual logic into the class. After finishing the implementation for the last method, and making sure all the unit tests passed I then started working on the class that needs to use the config file handler.

However, whilst starting to develop the other class, I realised that part of my config file handler implementation would not suffice, so I had to re-write some of the methods - this then broke tons of my unit tests for the config file handler.

In this instance, should I re-write those tests? Or should I have kept the original methods and written additional ones?

Comment: Is anyone else going to use methods you originally wrote? If not, there is no point keeping dead code.

Comment: Something I find beneficial is to define a Interface for the class in question.  And my Unit Tests will only test the public Methods and Properties of the interface.  Then if I need to refactor and change my internal implementation my unit tests shouldn't break.  My unit tests will only need to be modified if I change the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Do not keep the original methods if they are not needed.  That is the essence of refactoring.  Correct the unit tests as needed and discard tests that are no longer relevant.

Comment: In fact, I believe it was a mistake to write the methods you thought you would need. This is one of the values of TDD. You should have only written unit tests which you needed to have pass, and you should only have written the code necessary to make those tests pass. I would have written the tests first for the code that was going to _use_ the configuration class. That would have told you what tests were needed for the config class.

Comment: OK, so the mistake was starting at the bottom? I should have started higher up, and created the tests and classes that are required at the time as I go along?

Comment: It was not a mistake.  One should start not high or low, but simple, with what you think is the first test case.  It really doesn't matter at what level of abstraction.  If you weren't ready to write the configuration class, then start simpler as you did.

Comment: @Bruce: How would you know what the first test should be? I can only think about writing software in two ways; starting from the bottom and working up, or thinking about what the first Use Case would be and starting there... which is more like starting at the top and working to the bottom.

Comment: What broke in your Unit Tests?  Did you modify the public signature of the class OR did changing the internal implementation of the Class break your Unit Tests?

Comment: I might think that calling a function that will eventually open the  configuration file and returns an invalid handle as the only return value is the first test and seeing it fail is the first test.  Then  update the function to actually open a file...